# Rspec - testing model method - errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to create RSpec tests to test my suspension code below.

My code suspends one or more roles.

So an Item has several roles, each of which can be suspended by the suspend_roles method, by passing in the role ids.

It also sets the Item sub status to "Suspended" if all the roles are suspended.

This code is in the `Item` model:

```
def suspend_roles (role_ids)

        role_ids.each do |role_id|
          self.suspensions.create!(role_id: role_id, create_user_id: User.current_user.id)
        end

        if role_ids.count == Role.ids.count
          self.lifecycle_sub_status = "Suspended"
         self.save

        elsif role_ids.count < Role.ids.count && role_ids.count > 1
          self.lifecycle_sub_status = "Partial"
          self.save

        end
      end
```

Tests:

```
it 'suspends all roles' do

      test_item = create :item
      test_item.suspend_roles(Role.ids)
      expect(test_item.suspensions.count).to eq (Role.ids.count)
      expect(test_item.lifecycle_sub_status).to eq "Suspended"
    end
```

Now the problems:

1. Role.ids.count is returning nil, even though when I run my actual application it return a count of the ids.
2. User.current_user.id is also returning nil

This is the code for current_user in the Application controller:

```
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
      return @current_user
    end
  end
```

At the top of my tests I have:

```
let(:user) { create :user }
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What is in the `User.current` method?

Comment: sorry it should have been User.current_user.id, I have added in the code..

Comment: `User.current_user` will look for a `current_user` class method on the `User` class, so what is the code in the `User` model for that?

Comment: it calls the application controller current_user method, which is posted above..

Comment: Did you create any roles before your test?

Comment: No do I need a factory for the roles?  Do I not just pull them from the database, or do I need a factory for this?  I have a seed file which creates the roles in the DB

Comment: You'll be using a test db, which won't have any in - hence the nil.  Assuming you're using rails conventions the db tables will be truncated after each test